# Delete respective image in angular 10

Tags: angular, angular11

Tried to delete the respective image by Id but it deletes the first image every time I click the remove button. below is my code which I tried.

**Get image**

```
imageId: number;

this.imageService.getImage(this.productId).subscribe(m => {
  this.imageData = m;
  this.imageId = this.imageData[0].Id;
  console.log(m);
  console.log('ImageId ' + this.imageId);
});
```

**Delete method**

```
deleteImage() {
  this.imageService.deleteImage(this.imageId).subscribe(d => {
    console.log('Image removed')
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

**Html**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let img of imageData">
    <p [hidden]="true">{{img.Id}}</p>
    <img class="original" [alt]="img.Name" 
    src="https://localhost:44349/{{img.ImagePath}}" 
    width="350" 
    height="350" />
    <button type="submit" (click)="deleteImage()" class="btn btn-danger">
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
      Remove
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the id to the function, the id you actually want to delete, now you are using some variable `this.imageId`. So in your template, pass the id:

```
(click)="deleteImage(img.Id)"
```

and use that parameter in the delete:

```
deleteImage(id) {
  this.imageService.deleteImage(id).subscribe(d => {
   console.log('Image removed')
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Get Image**

```
this.imageService.getImage(this.productId).subscribe(m => {
  this.imageData = m;
});
```

**Delete Method**

```
deleteImage(Id: any):any {
    this.imageService.deleteImage(Id).subscribe(d => {
      console.log('Image removed')
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let img of imageData">
    <p [hidden]="true">{{img.Id}}</p>
    <img class="original" [alt]="img.Name" 
    src="https://localhost:44349/{{img.ImagePath}}" 
    width="350" 
    height="350" />
    <button type="submit" (click)="deleteImage(img.Id)" class="btn btn-danger">
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
      Remove
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```